# What is Misaligned Load and Misaligned store error?

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

I am getting a Misaligned Store error in my program at runtime. I know it is something related to pointer, but don't know what it is. If someone can explain, it would be helpful so I can fix the error.

```
The exception was 0x21, Misaligned store @ 0x1f1f1f1f
```

In the code I am copying some data into a statically defined array of a structures.
Below is an example.

```
struct MyStructure buffer[MAX_SIZE];    // MAX_SIZE is macro defined to 100.
printf("Address ptr: %p", &buffer[0].dataMember);
```

The above address is printing 0x1f1f1f1f.

Comment: Check memory problems with valgrind for exemple. You have some wierd memory issues. 0x1f1f1f1f look like you overflowed some array and thus rewrite a pointer to this weird address. This is my two cents guess and you can not expect more help without any code and input anyway

Comment: @ninjaconcombre I just want to know what this error "misaligned store" means.

Comment: To some extent that's going to be architecture dependent (at least for the address) but in general terms it means that you've smashed something into your static array. Check whether there are any `#pragma pack()` statements in the struct definition, too